# Docusign Powerform Activate Only 302

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex-code, apex

I am trying to activate a powerform link using the activate only parameter by sending a GET request from my APEX code with prefilled parameter fields. I am getting a 302 Status Found when using Http callout.

If I use that same url manually in chrome browser window however, it works fine and activates the powerform and sends emails out to listed recipients as it should.

Comment: 3xx codes are redirects. What happens if you load the URL in the location header of the response?

Comment: @j3hyde WIll try to debug more but the logging the res only gives me {Status: 'Found', Code: 302}

Comment: This occurs when a resource or page you're attempting to load has been temporarily moved to a different location -- via a 302 redirect. ... It's important to note that an HTTP 302 status code is caused by the web server you're attempting to reach. Have you rerun this lately?